# Javascript Map library using canvas like base

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

We've been working with several libraries like GoogleMaps, OpenLayers, ModestMaps... Even we've written a cartographic visor (Java Applet) that dealed with WMS servers several years ago. Of course this visor is currently useless.

Now we want to develop one FULL HTML5 visor because we're having lots of trouble dealing with the most common frameworks (performance, licensing,design ...). We build advanced and technical maps applications for GIS expert.

We want to draw vectors inside a canvas element. We don't want to draw a canvas object over the base map (like we can do with GoogleMaps ...) , we've been dealing with that and it's not the best way, we need a base object as a canvas HTML5 object in which draw directly.

The question is: Is there a free library that renders on a canvas object which we can extend?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be the answer: http://leafletjs.com/. This library does everything that we want, it draws vectors on canvas or SVG, draws tiles maps, good integration with geojson and more...It is far and away the best choice.

Certanly this library doesn't use a unique canvas object, but it's even better.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a maps API that will draw the map using html5 canvas. It looks like https://github.com/dfacts/Slippy-Map-On-Canvas/ uses the Open Street Maps API to get map tiles and then draws them on the canvas. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: Nop, we are looking for a library more powerfull... I've updated my answer, Leafletjs is really cool. Thx for your answer